# Show nested_fields in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a weird problem with "nested_form" in Rails. I made a model "evaluate" associated to other model "proyect", but when I try to show theres fields, on "proyects" form, just show fields from "proyects".

Here is my code:

**Models:**

*proyect.erb*

```
class Proyect < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :vercions #I know is versions
has_many :evaluates #I know is evaluators
accepts_nested_attributes_for :evaluates, allow_destroy: true
validates :titulo,:presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 3 }
validates :descripcion,:presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 3 }


end
```

*evaluate.erb*

```
class Evaluate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :proyect
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**Controller**
*proyects_controller.erb*

```
class ProyectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_proyect, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /proyects
  # GET /proyects.json
  def index

      if current_user.tipo == 'i'
            @proyects = Proyect.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
            else
        @proyects = #Proyect.where(:id_user => current_user.id)
              Proyect.all
      end
  end



  # GET /proyects/1
  # GET /proyects/1.json
  def show
    @vercion = Vercion.new
  end

  # GET /proyects/new
  def new
    @proyect = Proyect.new
    @proyect.evaluates.build
  end

  # GET /proyects/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /proyects
  # POST /proyects.json
  def create
    @proyect = current_user.proyects.new(proyect_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @proyect.save
        format.html { redirect_to @proyect, notice: 'Proyecto creado!.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @proyect }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @proyect.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      # Llamamos al   ActionMailer que creamos

      Usermailer.bienvenido_email(current_user,@proyect).deliver
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /proyects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /proyects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @proyect.update(proyect_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @proyect, notice: 'Proyect was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @proyect }

      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @proyect.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /proyects/1
  # DELETE /proyects/1.json
  def destroy
    @proyect.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to proyects_url, notice: 'Proyect was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_proyect
      @proyect = Proyect.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def proyect_params
      params.require(:proyect).permit(
        :titulo, :descripcion,:evaluador, :id_user, :codigo, :user_assign,evaluates_attributes: [:id,:nombre, :prioridad, :_destroy,  user_ids: []  ])
    end
end
```

**Views**
*_form.html.erb (Proyects)*

```
<%= nested_form_for(@proyect) do |f| %>
  <% if @proyect.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@proyect.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this proyect from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @proyect.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :titulo %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :titulo %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :descripcion %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :descripcion %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :id_user, :value => current_user.id %> 
  </div>
  <!--Aqui añadi algo-->
  <fieldset id="evaluates">
    <%= f.fields_for :evaluates do |evaluates_form| %>
      <div class="field">      
        <%= evaluates_form.label :status %><br>
        <%= evaluates_form.text_field :status %>
      </div>
      <%= evaluates_form.link_to_remove "Eliminar esta tarea" %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= f.link_to_add "Agregar una tarea", :evaluates %></p>
  </fieldset>
 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*_evaluate_fields.html.erb*

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :status, 'Nombre de la tarea' %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :status %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :user_ids, User.where(:tipo => 'e'), :id, :cedula %>
</div>
<%= f.link_to_remove "Eliminar Evaluador" %>
```

Comment: I don't see the evaluate attribute `:status` permitted in `project_params`.  Could that be causing it?

Comment: No, my friend. Actually i have that line like: def proyect_params
      params.require(:proyect).permit(
        :titulo, :descripcion,:evaluador, :id_user, :codigo, :user_assign,evaluates_attributes: [:id, :status, :_destroy,  user_ids: []  ])
    end

Comment: so your actual code is different than what you posted?  please update your question with the latest code